# How to get variable from php to array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```html
<?php
include 'config.php';

$id_tes = $_GET['id_tes'];


  $i = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='I' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $e = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='E' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $n = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='N' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $s = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='S' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $t = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='T' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $f = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='F' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $j = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='J' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
  $p = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) FROM report WHERE jawaban='P' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");

 
$dataPoints1 = array(
  array("label"=> "Intorvert dan Extrovert", "y"=> 56),
  array("label"=> "Sensing dan Intuition", "y"=> 76),
  array("label"=> "Thinking & Feeling", "y"=> 89),
  array("label"=> "Judging & Perceiving", "y"=> 35)
);
$dataPoints2 = array(
  array("label"=> "Intorvert dan Extrovert", "y"=> 75),
  array("label"=> "Sensing dan Intuition", "y"=> 43),
  array("label"=> "Thinking & Feeling", "y"=> 54),
  array("label"=> "Judging & Perceiving", "y"=> 34)
);
  
?>
```

How to get the value of a variable in php to be displayed in an array to replace a number value (56, 76, 89, 35, 75, 43, 54, 34) to be the result of a variable count of ($ i, $ e, $ n, etc).

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( $dataPoints1 as $key=>$item ) {
    echo $item['y'];
    echo $item['label']
    //replace
    $dataPoints1[$key]['y'] = $replace_value;
}
```

Comment: where i use to put that codes ? sorry i'm new in programming.

Comment: Change this code, you should see count(id_tes) number, then inside it - foreach dataPoints but remember to change $item In second foreach to $item2 or like that, to avoid duplicate.

$i = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id_tes) as id_tes_count FROM report WHERE jawaban='I' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes");
if(!empty($i)) {
foreach( $I as $item ) {
    echo $item['id_tes_count'];
}
}

Comment: I guess that DB tables handles dataPoints labels as well, so you could do this in query:

    SELECT label, count(id_tes) as y FROM report WHERE jawaban='I' and id_tes='$id_tes' GROUP BY id_tes

but report table should have label column.

Comment: $dataPoints1 = array(
  array("label"=> "Intorvert dan Extrovert", "y"=> 56),
  array("label"=> "Sensing dan Intuition", "y"=> 76),
  array("label"=> "Thinking & Feeling", "y"=> 89),
  array("label"=> "Judging & Perceiving", "y"=> 35)
);         is changed to be -->    foreach( $dataPoints1 as $key=>$item ) {
    echo $item['y'];
    echo $item['label']
    //replace
    $dataPoints1[$key]['y'] = $i;
}      OR  replace on number of "y" (56, 76, 89, 35, 75, 43, 54, 34)......... sorry i'm still confuse.

Comment: i'm not have DB tables "dataPoints".. i'm just take a code from website : https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/ and put it on my codes.

Comment: So in database You should have x and y and label if You wish to draw chart from this data. If I don't know what is correct database table structure I can't help You.